# Key error in dictionary while deleting the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to count the string and I want to delete the key with value 1 and 2. I am successfully able to count the strings with below script. If I am adding if loop to the dictionary its throwing Key error 'd' when I try to print it.

```
s = "aaabbbd"
def check_freq(s):
     freq = {}
     for c in s:
        freq[c] = s.count(c)
     for w in sorted(freq, key=freq.get, reverse=True):
         if freq[w] == 1:
             del freq[w]
             print (w, freq[w])

check_freq(s)
```

Error is below

```
File "<ipython-input-60-a79c71ac1b31>", line 10, in check_freq
    print (w, freq[w])

KeyError: 'd'
```

Expected output

> {'a': 3, 'b': 3}

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. It works fine for me

Comment: I want to delete the key with value 1 in this case key 'd' has to deleted. So if uncomment my if loop (#if freq[w] == 1: #del freq[w])   it will throw error

Comment: do you still have the print statement there after deletion? cuz that will error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete the key, how can you print it? Because the key is deleted, it raises a KeyError as the key is no longer present. Just add a continue when you delete it.

```
s = "aaabbbd"
def check_freq(s):
    freq = {}
    for c in s:
        freq[c] = s.count(c)
    for w in sorted(freq, key=freq.get, reverse=True):
        if freq[w] == 1:
            del freq[w]
            continue
        print (w, freq[w])
    return freq
result = check_freq(s)

>a 3
b 3

result 
> {'a': 3, 'b': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

By deleting the entry from the `freq` dictionary you cannot print it anymore; it doesn't exist. You could add an else clausule to prevent this:

```
 for w in sorted(freq, key=freq.get, reverse=True):
     if freq[w] == 1:
         del freq[w]
     else:
         print (w, freq[w])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError` is happening because when you write

```
if freq[w] == 1:
    del freq[w]
    print (w, freq[w])
```

for `w = 'd'`, `freq[w] = 1`. So, you are deleting `freq[w]` but in the next line, you are trying to print `freq[w]` which doesn't exist.
You could avoid this by using an `if-else` clause.

```
s = "aaabbbd"
def check_freq(s):
    freq = {}
    for c in s:
        freq[c] = s.count(c)
    for w in sorted(freq, key=freq.get, reverse=True):
        if freq[w] == 1 or freq[w] == 2:
            del freq[w]
        else:
            print (w, freq[w])
print(freq)

check_freq(s)
```

#### Output:

```
a 3
b 3
{'a': 3, 'b': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
s = "aaabbbd"

def check_freq(s):
    freq = {}
    for c in s:
        freq[c] = s.count(c)

    for key, value in freq.items():
        if value == 1:
            del freq[key]

    return freq

print check_freq(s)
```

**Output:**

{'a': 3, 'b': 3}

Actually you don't need to sort the dictionary. You just need to iterate through its elements and check whether the key is equal to one. Then delete this key-value pair from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Keep delete in try block and that worked for me.

```
try:
   del freq[w]
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of deleting keys, you could always rebuild a new dictionary with only keep keys with values greater than 2:

```
from collections import Counter

s = "aaabbbd"

counts = {k: v for k, v in Counter(s).items() if v > 2}

print(counts)
# {'a': 3, 'b': 3}
```

Which also uses [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to construct the counts. Using `s.count()` is very inefficient since it scans the whole string each time to count a character. This ends up being quadratic O(N^2), since it has to visit every character for each character. `Counter()` simply counts all the characters in one traversal, which is O(N).

If you want to delete from the same dictionary, you can iterate over a copy and delete from the original with [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop):

```
from collections import Counter

s = "aaabbbd"

counts = Counter(s)

count_items = list(counts.items())
for k, v in count_items:
    if v <= 2:
        counts.pop(k) # Or del counts[k]

print(counts)
# Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 3})
```

**Note:** `Counter()` is a subclass of `dict`, so you can treat them the same. Having said this, one of the differences is that `Counter()` doesn't raise `KeyError` when a key doesn't exist, it returns 0 instead.

This can be demonstrated here:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter({'a': 1})
>>> y = {'a': 1}
>>> x['b']
0
>>> y['b']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'b'
```